# Python: list index out of range

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa corto para probar Python, uno en el que eliges dos listas de números y te dice cuántos números de la segunda lista son múltiplos de todos los números de la primera

```
def esmultiplo (m,y,b):
if y % m != 0 and b == True:
        b = False
return b

def cuantosmultiplos (multiplos, lista):
n = 0
i = 0
j = 0
bool = True
for i in lista:
    for j in multiplos:
        bool = esmultiplo (multiplos[j], lista[i], bool)
    if bool == True:
        n = n + 1
return n

l = list(range(1,100))
m = [3,5]
n = 0
n = cuantosmultiplos(m, l)
print(n)
```

Y el problema es que me da el siguiente error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-a52f103b79ab> in <module>()
      2 m = [3,5]
      3 n = 0
----> 4 n = cuantosmultiplos(m, l)
      5 print(n)

<ipython-input-80-3ed7d41f67dd> in cuantosmultiplos(multiplos, lista)
      6     for i in lista:
      7         for j in multiplos:
----> 8             bool = esmultiplo (multiplos[j - 1], lista[i - 1], bool)
      9         if bool == True:
     10             n = n + 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Lo he revisado varias veces y no se que tengo mal. Soy bastante nuevo así que puede ser una tontería. Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Hola Juan, además del problema que causa la excepción tines otros problemas porque básicamente te estas complicando demasiado, por ejemplo usas la variable `bool` (nombre que no debes usar por otro lado), la cual  pasas a la función y que no necesita en realidad.El problema es que en la primera iteración si no es múltiplo esta variable pasa a ser `False` y a partir de ahí `esmultiplo` retorna siempre `False`. No se si entiendo que resultado buscas, por ejemplo ¿Para `[3, 5]` y `[1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 15]` que debería retornar (6 o 5)?. Es decir, 15 que es múltiplo de ambos se cuenta dos veces o una

Comment: El  son múltiplos de todos los números de la primera también puede interpretarse como que debe retorna 1 porque solo el 15 es múltiplo de todos y cada uno de los números de la otra lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos. He conseguido hacer que funciones cambiando el momento en el que declaro la variable booleana como Verdadera. Aun así seguiré revisando cómo podría hacer un código más ordenado y claro en general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que deberias cambiar esta linea
`bool = esmultiplo (multiplos[j], lista[i], bool)` por
`bool = esmultiplo (j, i, bool)`
Al iterar con un `for i in lista` lo que haces es iterar sobre la lista e ir poninedo cada valor en la variable `i`.

Comment: Pues ahora mismo ya no da error pero siempre me da 0. Puede ser que ya sea un error del código mismo. Más tarde lo revisaré. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si, con esto se soluciona tu pregunta, que era el error. Yo tambien creo que tienes algo mal en tu logica.